# How to use smlnj-lib in mlton

Tags: sml, mlton

I'm compiling an SML source file with reference to `IntBinarySet` using MLton. The code runs well using SML/NJ, however, when compiled using MLton, it complains `Undefined structure IntBinarySet`. Do I need to import the smlnj-lib somehow? (I can use `IntBinarySet` directly in SML/NJ without `use`-ing or importing anything)

To be specific, my source file `intset.sml` is as follows.

```
fun newSet () = IntBinarySet.empty
```

and MLton complains:

```
Error: intset.sml 1.17.
  Undefined structure IntBinarySet.
compilation aborted: parseAndElaborate reported errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLton has a good page [about smlnj-lib in MLton](http://www.mlton.org/SMLNJLibrary).

From your limited information, I assume that you are not importing smlnj-lib in your .mlb file?

[ORD_SET is part of the utility library](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/toc.html). Thus your problem should be fixed, having a reference to:

```
$(SML_LIB)/smlnj-lib/Util/smlnj-lib.mlb
```